# MongoDB: Grouping across multiple fields into one document per user

Tags: mongodb

Say I have the following documents:

```js
{ "user": 1, "guild": "a", "character": "Jim" },
{ "user": 1, "guild": "a", "character": "Tom" },
{ "user": 1, "guild": "b", "character": "Jerry" },
{ "user": 1, "guild": "c", "character": "Samantha" },
{ "user": 2, "guild": "a", "character": "Veronica" }
```

Each document represents a `character` that is owned by `user` in a particular `guild`. I need a query that generates one document per user with each of their characters matched to their specific guild in a subdocument.

**I essence, I want to achieve the following output:**

```js
{
    "user": 1,
    "characters": {
        "a": ["Jim", "Tom"],
        "b": ["Jerry"],
        "c": ["Samantha"]
    }
},
{
    "user": 2,
    "characters": {
        "a": ["Veronica"]
    }
}
```

The closest I've gotten so far is this:

```js
db.characters.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { "user": "$user", "guild": "$guild" },
      characters: { $push: "$character" }
    }
  }
])
```

However, this produces one document per `user`/`guild` combination:

```js
[
  { _id: { user: 1, guild: 'c' }, characters: [ 'Samantha' ] },
  { _id: { user: 1, guild: 'a' }, characters: [ 'Jim', 'Tom' ] },
  { _id: { user: 1, guild: 'b' }, characters: [ 'Jerry' ] },
  { _id: { user: 2, guild: 'a' }, characters: [ 'Veronica' ] }
]
```

Comment: the output you want has data on keys, and to do those in Mongo its more complicated, 
how about  ```{
    "user": 1,
    "characters": 
    [
      {"guild" : "a"
       "names" : ["Jim", "Tom"]}
      {"guild": "b"
       "names" ["Jerry"]}
      ...
    ]
}```
I think this output is much more friendly to mongo, and you could make the queries much easier

Comment: @Takis_ That would work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there, just needed a couple of pipeline steps to create the desired outcome. In particular you need the [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) operator to convert an array of key/value object pairs that will map to your final result. To get this array first you would need a preceding [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) step to aggregate the characters and guild fields into key/value pairs and then a final [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) step to achieve the above.

So your full pipeline would like like the following:

```
db.characters.aggregate([
    { '$group': { 
        '_id': { "user": "$user", "guild": "$guild" },
        'characters': { '$push': "$character" } 
    } },
    { '$group': { 
        '_id': "$_id.user",
        'characters': { 
            '$push': {
               'k': { '$toString': '$_id.guild' },
               'v': '$characters'
            } 
        } 
    } },
    { '$addFields': {
       'characters': { '$arrayToObject': '$characters' } 
    } }
])
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I messed up a bit in my post, though. In order to simplify things, I changed the values of `user` and `guild`. They are both `Long`s, not `int` and `string` (respectively). As a result, Mongo's complaining that `k` must be type `string` but it got a `long` instead.

Comment: [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) will solve this problem

Comment: @chridam I didn't change my question, though? I meant that in my initial question, I gave data types that didn't exactly match my actual database.

Answer (score 1):

Almost the same query with the previous answer, just without data on keys (output is not the one you asked exactly)

If the data go to the application, and you will not store them in that form in the database, its fine, but if they will go back to the database, data on keys are difficult to handle so its best to avoid them i think.

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X7OdmDEn6qD)

Query

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "user": "$user",
        "guild": "$guild"
      },
      "character": {
        "$push": "$character"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.user",
      "characters": {
        "$push": {
          "guild": "$_id.guild",
          "character": "$character"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: The data *won't* be stored ... but why do you say it probably shouldn't be? I'm brand-new to MongoDB and coming from an SQL background.

Comment: because mongodb operators work on schema fields that have known names,for example how to group by an uknown field that has data?,you have to do slow and complicated things like `$ObjectToArray` and back to object, to give known names to the keys. [see this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68884011/aggregating-a-total-from-subdocuments-in-mongodb/68884209#68884209) But if those data just go to the application its fine to use it.